Screenplay formatting: How to get ~55 lines with 12 point Courier
All of the sources I've found suggest that screenplays use 1-inch margins on the top and bottom, 12-point Courier, 8.5" by 11" paper, and have approximately 55 lines per page.
(From nfi.edu):


12-point Courier Font
1.5 inch left margin
1-inch right margin (between 0.5 inches and 1.25 inches), ragged
1 inch top and bottom margins
Around 55 lines per page regardless of paper size. This excludes the page number and spaces
after it


Using Courier New on Microsoft Word with 1.0 line spacing and 8.5" by 11" paper size, only 47 lines will fit on the page. Switching to A4 gives me 51 lines.
Sources:

https://www.masterclass.com/articles/what-is-a-screenplay-formatting-tips-and-tricks
https://screencraft.org/blog/how-to-format-a-script/
https://blog.celtx.com/how-to-format-a-script/
https://www.studiobinder.com/blog/how-to-write-a-screenplay/
https://www.nfi.edu/screenplay-format/

Are these rules contradictory or am I missing something?

I guess your line spacing is too large.
Here are some of the pages from the script of the movie Ex Machina overlaid over each other:

As you can see, there are 58 lines in that script.
A line spacing of 1.0 in Word means 120% of the font size. Maybe you need to reduce it below 1.0 to something like 0.9.
The lines in the Ex Machina script are pretty close together. Here is an image of the text of the script (in black) with the same text in Apple Pages with a line spacing of 1.0 (in pink) overlaid:

I don't have Word, but I believe it will look similar. As you can see, the line spacing in the script is less than 1.0.

Thanks, I got this to work! When you choose custom line spacing options in Word there is an option for an exact amount measured in points. Setting to 12pt (same as the font size) seems to work and gives me 58 lines per page.
